# Getting two trinkets to talk to each other via the serial pins

Tags: serial, adafruit

I'm trying to make a quick proof of concept of two trinket M0s talking to each other via their RX and TX pins and I'm not able to get it working.

I uploaded sender and receiver sketches to two trinkets:

```cpp
//sender.ino
char state[10] = "hello";

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.write(state, 5);
    delay(1000);
}
```

```cpp
//receiver.ino
char state[10];

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("reading bytes");
    Serial.readBytes(state, 10);
    Serial.println(state);
    delay(1000);
}
```

After the uploads I wired the two trinkets together, jumping the RX of the first to the TX of the other and TX of the first to the RX of the other. I also connected their grounds to have a common ground.

[image: wiring]

I plugged the sender into a battery and the receiver into my computer. The problem I'm running into is that when I look at the serial monitor for the receiver instead of getting the expected "hello" I'm getting broken strings of "TestingOpen":

[image: serial output]

I double checked [the pinout diagram and guide for the Trinket M0](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-trinket-m0-circuitpython-arduino/pinouts) to make sure I was using the correct RX/TX pins (pin 3 for RX, 4 for TX) and it all seems fine but obviously something is still going wrong.

Anyone know what I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you should use `if (Serial.available())` before starting to read with readBytes. now you print random memory

2) readBytes is blocking. it waits for the next character until a timeout. default timeout is 1 second. after "hello" was received it waits a second. you could use readBytesUntil and some 'separator' character for example '\n' (new line)

3) readBytes returns the count of bytes read. you should use it to terminate the buffer

```
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.println("reading bytes");
    size_t l = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', state, 10);
    state[l] = 0;
    Serial.println(state);
  }
}
```